# Is Doctor Strange's "Power" Just a Skill?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange*, Stephen Strange learns magic after seeking to fix his hands. When he is training, there are large numbers of people training alongside him, as seen below.

[image: Doctor Strange]

In the video below from *Doctor Strange: In the Multiverse of Madness*, America Chavez is learning magic. IMO, this implies that magic can be learnt by **anyone**, so is more of a skill than a "superpower". Is this assumption correct?

Comment: I object to the word “just”. Even if it is a skill, he wouldn’t be the only marvel superhero who “just” has skills

Comment: America Chavez has quite a number of exceptional powers of her own. I am not sure the fact that any one person, let alone someone who already has powers, can learn magic, demostrates that anyone can.

Comment: I also tend to call it a skill. Why should someone require a physical tool (sling ring) to be able to perform magic? Shouldn't magic come from soul?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *implied* that it's a learnable skill/ability.

> Without a doubt, the most in-depth explanation for the presence of magic within the MCU has to come from the film Doctor Strange. In one scene of the film, the Ancient One (Tilda Swinton) explains to Dr. Stephen Strange (Benedict Cumberbatch) how they harness and use magic. For them, spells are created as follows: "We harness energy drawn from other dimensions of the multiverse to cast spells, to conjure shields and weapons...to make magic." The Ancient One describes spells as being synonymous with programs, "...the source code that shapes reality."
>
> **In this way, it is elaborated that spells are not necessarily usable only by those gifted with innate magical properties, but by anyone given enough time and practice with the arts.** This lines up similarly with the concept provided for Wanda's ability to use magic, though in her scenario the magic was not learned but rather granted through experimentation. For Stephen Strange to become as powerful with magic as he is depicted in later films, he had to study and practice a multitude of spells and rituals.
>
> [Source](https://collider.com/how-does-magic-work-in-mcu-doctor-strange-wanda/)

Whether **anyone** can "harness energy drawn from other dimensions" is open to question but the MCU does not go into further detail.

Comment: It seems like magic in the MCU is a lot like many skills in real life: anyone can learn it and become good at it with enough effort, but not everyone has the same talent for it.

Comment: For instance, Wanda is not the sorcerer who put the most effort into practicing, after all. She's like the Manute Bol or Yao Ming of magic, to use an basketball analogy: if they had never played basketball in their lives, they'd barely be able to dunk, but once they had a decent amount training, you or I would never be better than them no matter how much we had practiced.